# ORACLE | JSON_QUERY with path as variable

Tags: json, oracle12c

Is that possible to pass the variable path on JSON_QUERY? I've tried this

```
select
   t1.ID,
   JSON_QUERY(PRC_DATA, t2.key WITH WRAPPER)
from
   TEST_JSON T1,
   TEMPLATES T2
```

But it returns the following error

```
ORA-40454: path expression not a literal
40454. 00000 -  "path expression not a literal"
*Cause:    The provided path expression was not a literal (a constant).
*Action:   Provide a constant path expression.
Error at Line: 9 Column: 35
```

I don't want to use `Execute Immediate`, because I want to `INSERT-SELECT` this `JSON` keys into a table.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON path expression has to be a literal. We cannot work with case where the path to be evaluated is defendant on some other row, or even the same row.